# How can I replace pandas.dataframe.describe() with a SQL query?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to compare tables in different databases. When I use the describe() method in pandas I run out of memory. So I want to run a similar SQL query. I'm thinking to get a list of columns and their types. Then run numeric aggregations on some columns and string functions on the other columns. Then union the results. Has someone already done this?